# Error building glibc2.23

Tags: linux, gnu-make, gnu, glibc

I'm trying to build the latest version (2.23) of `glibc` on an older version
of linux. For that, I rebuilt the latest versions of `gcc` and `binutils`.

```
~/software/include >uname -a
Linux 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Aug 10 09:44:54 EDT 2015 x86_64
x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

~/software/include >gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 5.3.0

~/software/include >make --version
GNU Make 3.81

~/software/include >ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.26.20160125
```

I then configured glibc as follows:

```
~/software/tmp/glibc-build >../glibc-2.23/configure --prefix=$HOME/software --enable-add-ons=linuxthreads
```

However, make fails with the following (and more) errors. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
~/software/tmp/glibc-build >make

...
...

    ./../include/libc-symbols.h:24:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘IN_MODULE’
 #define IS_IN(lib) (IN_MODULE == MODULE_##lib)
                     ^
./../include/libc-symbols.h:651:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘IS_IN’
 #if IS_IN (libnss_nisplus)
     ^
/users/PAS0272/osu5388/software/tmp/glibc-build/libc-modules.h:15:16: error: token "." is not valid in preprocessor expressions
 #define MODULE_.*-.*-linux.* 19
                ^
./../include/libc-symbols.h:32:30: note: in definition of macro ‘PASTE_NAME1’
 #define PASTE_NAME1(a,b)     a##b
                              ^
./../include/libc-symbols.h:23:19: note: in expansion of macro ‘PASTE_NAME’
 #define IN_MODULE PASTE_NAME (MODULE_, MODULE_NAME)
                   ^
./../include/libc-symbols.h:23:31: note: in expansion of macro ‘MODULE_’
 #define IN_MODULE PASTE_NAME (MODULE_, MODULE_NAME)
                               ^
./../include/libc-symbols.h:24:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘IN_MODULE’
 #define IS_IN(lib) (IN_MODULE == MODULE_##lib)
                     ^
./../include/libc-symbols.h:680:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘IS_IN’
 #if IS_IN (libutil)
     ^
/users/PAS0272/osu5388/software/tmp/glibc-build/libc-modules.h:15:16: error: token "." is not valid in preprocessor expressions
 #define MODULE_.*-.*-linux.* 19
                ^
./../include/libc-symbols.h:32:30: note: in definition of macro ‘PASTE_NAME1’
 #define PASTE_NAME1(a,b)     a##b
                              ^
./../include/libc-symbols.h:23:19: note: in expansion of macro ‘PASTE_NAME’
 #define IN_MODULE PASTE_NAME (MODULE_, MODULE_NAME)
                   ^
./../include/libc-symbols.h:23:31: note: in expansion of macro ‘MODULE_’
 #define IN_MODULE PASTE_NAME (MODULE_, MODULE_NAME)
                               ^
./../include/libc-symbols.h:24:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘IN_MODULE’
 #define IS_IN(lib) (IN_MODULE == MODULE_##lib)
                     ^
../sysdeps/generic/symbol-hacks.h:3:31: note: in expansion of macro ‘IS_IN’
 #if !defined __ASSEMBLER__ && IS_IN (libc) && defined SHARED
                               ^
In file included from ../signal/signal.h:361:0,
                 from ../include/signal.h:5,
                 from <stdin>:2:
../linuxthreads/sysdeps/pthread/bits/pthreadtypes.h:52:3: error: conflicting types for ‘pthread_attr_t’
 } pthread_attr_t;
   ^
In file included from ../signal/signal.h:80:0,
                 from ../include/signal.h:5,
                 from <stdin>:2:
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/bits/siginfo.h:316:30: note: previous declaration of ‘pthread_attr_t’ was here
 typedef union pthread_attr_t pthread_attr_t;
                              ^
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
/users/PAS0272/osu5388/software/tmp/glibc-build/libc-modules.h:15:16: error: token "." is not valid in preprocessor expressions
 #define MODULE_.*-.*-linux.* 19
                ^
./../include/libc-symbols.h:32:30: note: in definition of macro ‘PASTE_NAME1’
 #define PASTE_NAME1(a,b)     a##b
                              ^
./../include/libc-symbols.h:23:19: note: in expansion of macro ‘PASTE_NAME’
 #define IN_MODULE PASTE_NAME (MODULE_, MODULE_NAME)
                   ^
./../include/libc-symbols.h:23:31: note: in expansion of macro ‘MODULE_’
 #define IN_MODULE PASTE_NAME (MODULE_, MODULE_NAME)
                               ^
./../include/libc-symbols.h:24:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘IN_MODULE’
 #define IS_IN(lib) (IN_MODULE == MODULE_##lib)
                     ^
../include/signal.h:65:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘IS_IN’
 #  if IS_IN (rtld)
       ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/users/PAS0272/osu5388/software/tmp/glibc-build/ucontext_i.h] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/users/PAS0272/osu5388/software/tmp/glibc-2.23/csu'
make[1]: *** [csu/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/users/PAS0272/osu5388/software/tmp/glibc-2.23'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered one solution.

Earlier I had extracted the `linuxthreads` tarball from the `glibc` [download page](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-linuxthreads-2.5.tar.bz2) into the `glibc-2.23/` source directory and was trying run `make` with `--enable-add-ons=linuxthreads` specified during configuration.

Removing this step allows the `make` of `glibc` to  complete without errors.

However, the new the question is now how should I build `glibc` with `linuxthreads` support